# How i get img from rss by php

Tags: php, rss

i want to get  from rss feeds by php or get this item

```
<enclosure url="http://www.youm7.com//images/newspics/large/S1220131618953.jpg " length="5000" type="image/jpge"/>
```

i use this code to get other item

```
<?

require_once 'rss_fetch.inc';
$url = 'http://egyptian-planet.com/rss.php';
$rss = fetch_rss($url);

echo "Site: ", $rss->channel['title'], "<br>";

foreach ($rss->items as $item ) {
    $title = $item[title];
    $url   = $item[link];
    $pub   = $item[pubdate];
    $desc  = $item[description]; 

    echo "<a href=$url>$title</a></li><br>";
    echo "$pub<br>";
    echo "<p>$desc</p><br>";
    echo "<br>";
}   
?>
```

Any help?

Comment: Add `print_r( $item );` into your `foreach` loop and look at the output array/object structure. This should help you to find the property you need.

Comment: @AeroX i dont found img in array

Comment: If you want to post up an edit to your question with one of those array structures that might help us help you a bit more. Currently we don't know how your `fetch_rss()` function works.

Comment: Side note: if `$item[title]` is not triggering a notice then you haven't configured PHP to display all error messages. Try to fix that since it only makes coding harder.

Comment: There's no `<enclosure>` tag at `http://egyptian-planet.com/rss.php`... :-?

Comment: [link]http://www.youm7.com/new3agelrss.asp [/link]

Comment: `<enclosure>` any way try this feed [link]youm7.com/new3agelrss.asp [/link] @ÁlvaroG.Vicario G. Vicario